# Android sort ListView alphabetically

Tags: android, sorting, listview, android-arrayadapter

So I'm trying to sort a simple `ArrayAdapter` for ListView. Here's what I've tried:

```
ListView lv;
String[] months = {
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "September",
        "October",
        "November",
        "December"
};

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ArrayList<String> list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, months);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.sortasc:
            list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(months));
            Collections.sort(list);
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(list.get(i));
            }
            adapter.clear();
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        case R.id.sortdesc:

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

But I'm getting `UnsupportedOperationException`, what's wrong with this? I really need help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You didn't called setAdapter(adapter), after sorting your items.

Use like below

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

instead of

```
adapter.clear(); // Useless 
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: this helps me, my bad I forgot to call the setAdapter method

Comment: I think you dont need to recreate and use setAdapter everytime...just update the source (months array) and call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

Comment: @umair.ali If you change instance of Adapter you always need to call `setAdapter`. You should verify at your side first...

Comment: @PankajKumar But i'm trying to raise the point that you have no need to pass "list" after sorting and creating new instance of adapter here...just reassign sorted array back to months like **months = (String[]) sortedMonthsList.toArray();** and call "adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()".

Comment: I've just add a generic sort widget to github. Use this code for sorting Listviews including those with multiple fields per row. https://github.com/davidlad123/SortAttributes

Answer (score 15):

Here is the trick...

```
private void sortAscending () {
    List<String> sortedMonthsList = Arrays.asList(months);
    Collections.sort(sortedMonthsList);

    months = (String[]) sortedMonthsList.toArray();
}
```

And for sortAscending, call

```
sortAscending();
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

Similarly, you can implement custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) for sort descending as well...

Hope this helps...:)

Answer (score 8):

```
Comparator<String> ALPHABETICAL_ORDER1 = new Comparator<String>() { 
    public int compare(String object1, String object2) {
        int res = String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(object1.toString(), object2.toString()); 
        return res;
    }
}; 

Collections.sort(your array name, ALPHABETICAL_ORDER1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Android sort listview alphabetically.

```
listAdapter = new AppsAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.content_layout,appList);
        final Collator col = Collator.getInstance();
        listAdapter.sort(new Comparator<ApplicationInfo>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ApplicationInfo lhs, ApplicationInfo rhs) {
                return col.compare(lhs.loadLabel(packageManager),rhs.loadLabel(packageManager));
            }
        });
```

Comment: what is the 'packgeManager' please ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Sort your array.
2. Recreate adapter.
3. Apply adapter to listview.

Comment: I've updated my code but still to no avail. It's still getting the same exception.

Comment: I'm trying to extend my baseadapter right now, give it some standard sorting methods and have it notify itself. Should be fun, though I'm not sure this will work.

Answer (score 1):

To sort a list, you need to use a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). You need to sort the underlying collections using a comparator that does alphabetical sorting and then notify the list to update itself.

Here's an example of doing this using an ArrayAdapter : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8920348/1369222

Answer (score 0):

its simple if you already have another adapter you can just copy paste this code under declaration of adapter

```
adapter.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String arg1, String arg0) {
            return arg1.compareTo(arg0);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than add data directly to your adapter, you can add them in Collection. Than sort the collection by using compactor. and finally...

```
adapter.addAll(collectionData);
```