# Android Listview sort by name (alphabet)

Tags: android

I tried to sort the listview by username alphabet but it is not work.
This is my code:

```
    session.friends.sort(new Comparator<Friend>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Friend friend, Friend info) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

Sort to friend.username

Comment: Change to your `return` with your `friendname` from your `Friend` Object.

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676781/android-sort-listview-alphabetically

Comment: `Android Listview sort by name`. Wrong. You will sort the list which you give the adapter.

Answer (score 1):

This is worked for me!

```
public void add(Friend object) {
    friends.add(object);
    Collections.sort(friends, new Comparator<Friend>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Friend friend, Friend info) {
            return friend.publicname.compareTo(info.publicname);
        }
    });
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    super.add(object);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Comparator](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Comparator.html), [Comparable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Comparable.html) and [Collator](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Collator.html).

To sort your objects by string you can use:

```
session.friends.sort(new Comparator<Friend>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Friend friend, Friend info) {
        Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());

        return collator.compare(friend.username, info.username);
    }
});
```

Comment: Call it before setting adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot leave the body of compare() empty else java wouldn't know what to compare try this -->

```
public int compare(Friend friend1, Friend friend2) {
    String name1 = friend1.getName().toLowerCase();
    String name2 = friend2.getName().toLowerCase();

    // asc order
    return name1.compareTo(name2);

    // desc order
    return name2.compareTo(name1);
}
```

Comment: This is not work too :( i have this onder the setAdapter

Comment: if by under setAdapter you mean after setAdapter then you must sort the array of friends before you instantiate the adapter or in its constructor. Or when you sort it afterwards you should call onNotifyDatasetChanged() on your adapter for it to reflect changes.