# Arrange list of items in Android Studio (Alphabetically, Most Recent... etc)

Tags: android, arraylist, cursor

I have an arraylist that I am striving to rearrange when the view is loaded. Curious if there are built in methods or ways to sort a list of items that I retrieve let's say in alphabetical order. I currently retrieve the items in the list from the cursor from oldest in the database on top to newest on bottom. I also want to find ways to reverse that to get newest on top. Any advice on such things? Or is this too particular?

Comment: use comparable for arraylist

Comment: Check this once. It may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676781/android-sort-listview-alphabetically

Answer (score 1):

To sort your list,

```
Collections.sort(list, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

and to reverse your list,

```
Collections.reverse(list);
```

Comment: How do Collections work hand in hand with ArrayList? If you can give me an example suppose I have an ArrayList filled with items and I called it array_List_Help. @Darshan

Comment: not getting what you are saying, it seems like you don't know much about Collection classes. I suggest you to refer this link,  
http://www.javatpoint.com/collections-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You can simply reverse an ArrayList by

```
Collections.sort(arraylist, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

further you can sort w.r.t name, age, number etc by

```
Collections.sort(unsortedList,new Comparator<YourModel>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(YourModela, YourModelb) {
        return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
    }
});
```

Comment: How do Collections work hand in hand with ArrayList? If you can give me an example suppose I have an ArrayList filled with items and I called it array_List_Help.