# How to sort Android Listview / HashMap

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, hashmap, linkedhashmap

i need a little help with my listview / hashmap.

I want to sort my listView by int values (TAG_EPOCH).

During my search on internet i found out that i might need a LinkedHashMap or a TreeSet but i don't understand how to use them with my existing code.

Here is an example of my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ...
}

static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
private static final String TAG_EPOCH = "dateEpoch";

private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        ListView dummyView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter();
        for (int i = 1; i < contactList.size(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> c = contactList.get(i);
            mAdapter.addItem(TAG_EPOCH);
        }
        dummyView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I guess this should help :

>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908549/sorting-of-listview-by-name-of-the-product-using-custom-adaptor/8920348#8920348

Answer (score 4):

You can try to implement a Comparator
In your class

```
class Contact implements Comparable<Contact>
```

Then add this:

```
public static final Comparator<Contact> INTEGER_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<Contact>() {
    // Overriding to sort on your integer
    public int compare(Contact c1, Contact c2) {
        return c1.integer - c1.integer;
    }
};
```

Then sort it using:

```
Collections.sort(list, Contact.INTEGER_COMPARATOR);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should sort your listview?

Set a list of items in the adapter like

ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

// Add values to list

sorting an arraylist is easier with Compare

[Sorting ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666382/sorting-arraylist)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Collections.sort()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%3CT%3E,%20java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20T%3E%29) methods to sort your ArrayList